# Issue in .net core build using docker in Azure devops

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-devops, yaml

I am currently setting up a dockerfile for .netcore buildandpush in Azure Devops for a .netcore project.
I am facing the below error at the "RUN dotnet restore".

```
The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1.
```

I am using the below SDK for build.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
```

I have tried modifying the above with the build specified , I am getting same error.
1.Should I add any task for installing .NEt core SDK in yaml file?
2.I am having one solution file and 4 csproj files. Its giving multiple dlls when I build using Visual studio.In the dockerfile I have given only the below :

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Example.dll"]
```

How do I pass all dlls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happened to me, this is microsoft CLI tools not working properly on linux... Depending on the context, it will often ignore the environment variables. To select your version of dotnet, simply add this command before interacting with dotnet, this will force dotnet to use the proper version

```sh
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.2.401 --force
```

Update this command to match your dotnet version

Comment: Thank you . It fixed the error. Is there a way to pass multiple dlls in docket entrypoint?

Comment: what do you mean, in what context would you need that? You want to run 2 apps at once?

Comment: its a microservice. So if I run the build in Visual Studio, its generating multiple dlls in release folder. I need all of them to pushed in the docker container

Comment: You need to add a copy command, then the entrypoint is just a command executing the DLL, ```COPY ./ /whereyourfileswillbecopied```, this will give you access to that then the command should be something like ```dotnet whereyourfileswillbecopied/somedll.dll```, does that answer your question?

Comment: you can refer to this for the docker command :p 
https://riptutorial.com/docker/example/11005/copy-instruction

Comment: Okay , so if there are 4 dll files , I have to write that many copy['dotnet', 'filepath/name.dll']. Thank you so much

Comment: And thanks a lot for the link provided . Much appreciated

Comment: You can simply copy the whole folder instead of individial files